# Set post data as a session (PHP/jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a form that users can bring with them on other pages and drag around (like Twitter's submit form). So once you hit "Write," a div will show up with the draggable form. I want it to set up so when I hit X on the div, it will submit to a page that will set it as a session, so when I hit "Write" again, the form will have all the information in it. Here's how I have it set up - the form:

```
<div id="writeOverlay"><form action="process.php" id="writeForm">
   <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['writeTitle"])){
      echo $_SESSION['writeTitle'];?>">
   <a href="#" id="writeExit">X</a>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form></div>
```

And when you click the X, jQuery handles it as such:

```
$('#writeExit').click(function(){
   $('#writeOverlay').hide();
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post('site.com/writeHandle.php', $('#writeForm').serialize(),function(){ // the $('#writeForm') was originally just $(this) but I changed it to see if I'd get different results. I did  not.
      console.log('Closed.');
   });
});
```

writeHandle.php works like this

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['writeTitle'] = $_POST['title'];
?>
```

Hitting the submit button works as it should, but when I hit exit, the session is not saved. So when I click "Write" again, the form will load as empty. I hope to be clear and concise with this issue. If more information is required, leave a comment and I'll be sure to update this.

Comment: If you open up a console window in your browser can you see the AJAX request being made?

Comment: It only says "Closed" so I'm pretty sure it was being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error. The `title` variable that you are trying to get in PHP is not sent properly. It should be send something like:

```
 ...,{title: "this is my title"}, function(){...}
```

So, edit your input tag:

```
<input id="title" ...... >
```

then your post code:

```
$.post(
   'site.com/writeHandle.php', 
   {
      title: $("#title").val()
   },
   function(){ // the $('#writeForm') was originally just $(this) but I changed it to see if I'd get different results. I did  not.
       console.log('Closed.');
   }
);
```

Comment: I think jQuery's serialize takes care of that. He is already calling serialize() on the form, which takes all of the inputs and converts them to key value pairs for posting. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Comment: That's what did it! Thanks, I've had this issue for a while.